# Hit with Unimplemented method StatusRuntimeException when unit testing generated grpc code in Android project

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, grpc

I have an Android project that generates gRPC classes from the proto file upon building, which is from here under the helloworld example:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src

My JUnit test follows to that of the test written for HelloWorldClient (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/example-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClientTest.kt), and I thought it theoretically would work

However, when I run the test, I was hit with an exception error as follows:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method helloworld.Greeter/SayHello is unimplemented
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:235)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:216)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:141)
    at io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc$GreeterBlockingStub.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:177)
    at com.android.grpcmvvm.data.GreeterRemoteDataSource.sayHello(GreeterRemoteDataSource.kt:49)
    at com.android.grpcmvvm.view.GreeterViewModelUnitTest.testTestFunction(GreeterViewModelUnitTest.kt:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at io.grpc.testing.GrpcCleanupRule$1.evaluate(GrpcCleanupRule.java:125)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Wanted but not invoked:
serviceImpl.sayHello(
    <Capturing argument>,
    <any>
);
-> at io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc$GreeterImplBase.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:101)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
serviceImpl.bindService();
-> at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:114)


Wanted but not invoked:
serviceImpl.sayHello(
    <Capturing argument>,
    <any>
);
-> at io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc$GreeterImplBase.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:101)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
serviceImpl.bindService();
-> at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.addService(AbstractServerImplBuilder.java:114)


    at io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc$GreeterImplBase.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:101)
    at com.android.grpcmvvm.view.GreeterViewModelUnitTest.testTestFunction(GreeterViewModelUnitTest.kt:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at io.grpc.testing.GrpcCleanupRule$1.evaluate(GrpcCleanupRule.java:125)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

The following is the test and the relevant code
(Please mind the ViewModel name. I removed anything about ViewModel from the test for the purpose of this question)

**GreeterViewModelUnitTest.kt**

```
import com.android.grpcmvvm.data.GreeterRemoteDataSource
import com.android.grpcmvvm.grpc.GrpcService
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloReply
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest
import io.grpc.inprocess.InProcessChannelBuilder
import io.grpc.inprocess.InProcessServerBuilder
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver
import io.grpc.testing.GrpcCleanupRule
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4
import org.mockito.*
import org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo
import org.mockito.internal.matchers.Any

@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class GreeterViewModelUnitTest {
    // region JUnit test rules
    @get:Rule
    val grpcCleanupRule = GrpcCleanupRule()

    private val serviceImpl = Mockito.mock(GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase::class.java, delegatesTo<Any>(object: GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase(){}))
    // endregion

    // region Private properties
    @Mock
    private lateinit var grpcService: GrpcService

    private lateinit var managedChannel: ManagedChannel

    private lateinit var greeterRemoteDataSource: GreeterRemoteDataSource
    // endregion

    @Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        val serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName()

        grpcCleanupRule.register(InProcessServerBuilder
            .forName(serverName)
            .directExecutor()
            .addService(serviceImpl)
            .build()
            .start())

        managedChannel = grpcCleanupRule.register(InProcessChannelBuilder
            .forName(serverName)
            .directExecutor()
            .build())

        Mockito.`when`(grpcService.createManagedChannel()).thenReturn(managedChannel)
        greeterRemoteDataSource = GreeterRemoteDataSource(grpcService)
    }

    @Test
    fun testTestFunction() {
        val requestCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HelloRequest::class.java)

        greeterRemoteDataSource.sayHello("once again")

        Mockito.verify<GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase>(serviceImpl)
            .sayHello(requestCaptor.capture(), ArgumentMatchers.any<StreamObserver<HelloReply>>())

        assertEquals("once again", requestCaptor.value.name)
    }
```

**GrpcService.kt**

```
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class GrpcService(private val host: String, private val port: Int) {

    fun createManagedChannel(): ManagedChannel {
        return ManagedChannelBuilder
            .forAddress(host, port)
            .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .usePlaintext()
            .build()
    }
}
```

**GreeterRemoteDataSource.kt**

```
import com.android.grpcmvvm.grpc.GrpcService
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloReply
import io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloRequest

class GreeterRemoteDataSource constructor(private val grpcService: GrpcService) {

    private lateinit var channel: ManagedChannel

    fun sayHello(message: String): String {
        channel = grpcService.createManagedChannel()

        val stub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
        val request = HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(message).build()

        val reply: HelloReply = try {
            stub.sayHello(request)
        } catch (e: StatusRuntimeException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return String.format("{0}", e.status)
        } finally {
            channel.shutdown()
        }

        return reply.message
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.grpcmvvm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def grpc_version = "1.22.1"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-alpha04"
    def mockito_kotlin_version = "2.1.0"
    def mockito_version = "3.0.0"
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    def truth_version = "0.45"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    // gRPC
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpc_version"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpc_version"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpc_version"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    // Instrumented tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'

    // Unit tests
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:$truth_version"
    testImplementation "io.grpc:grpc-testing:$grpc_version"
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:$mockito_kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-debug:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.1'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito_version"
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.22.1"
        }
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            javalite {}
        }
        ofNonTest()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                // Options added to --grpc_out
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm currently unable to find what exactly would cause such an error. I've also looked around for answers/insights to no avail.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implementation for `sayHello`, so the exception is correct:

```
    private val serviceImpl = Mockito.mock(GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase::class.java, delegatesTo<Any>(object: GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase(){}))
```

The example doesn't fail because HelloWorldClient catches the exception and logs it. If you look in `build/reports/tests/test/index.html` and navigate to HelloWorldClientTest, the Standard error includes:

```
Sep 18, 2019 9:18:11 AM io.grpc.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldClient greet
WARNING: RPC failed: Status{code=UNIMPLEMENTED, description=Method helloworld.Greeter/SayHello is unimplemented, cause=null}
```

To fix the problem, just provide a fake implementation of the sayHello method:

```
    private val serviceImpl = Mockito.mock(GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase::class.java, delegatesTo<Any>(object: GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase(){
        override fun sayHello(req: HelloRequest, responseObserver: StreamObserver<HelloReply>) {
            responseObserver.onNext(HelloReply.getDefaultInstance())
            responseObserver.onCompleted()
        }
    }))
```

I've filed [issue 6161](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6161) to make the example more clear.

Comment: I misunderstood which failure you were talking about. This all is true, but not the core problem of why the test failed.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I've missed that part to be honest.

As for mocking, like you have suggested I have changed for mockito-core and have resorted to Kotlin's all-open plugin to open up Kotlin classes I intend to mock in the test.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mockito-inline`, which is mocking a `final` method. If you swap to `mockito-core` then the test should pass. I tested this with the example-kotlin; swapping the mockito dependency to mockito-inline broke the test. I'll mention that overriding final methods is strongly unsupported by grpc-java.

As a quick fix you can use:

```
Mockito.`when`(grpcService.bindService()).thenCallRealMethod()
```